# Checking inequality

Tags: matrices, analysis, optimization, quadratic-programming

Let $\pi$ be a given permutation of the integers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let 
$$\mathcal{X}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \mid x_{\pi(1)}\geq\cdots\geq x_{\pi(n)},\mathbb{1}^\top x\geq \alpha\},$$
for some $\alpha>0$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ symmetric. Is there a way to check if 
\begin{align*}
a+b^{\top}x+x^{\top}Qx<0,\quad \forall x\in\mathcal{X},
\end{align*}
in general? For example, if $Q$ is negative semidefinite, then we can use convex quadratic programming to solve the problem. However, can we do something in the general case? Perhaps the eigendecomposition of $Q$ and the structure of $\mathcal{X}$ might be used.

Comment: My instinct says that there might not be an efficient way to establish the inequality, since what you want is essentially to maximize an non-concave quadratic over a polyhedron, which is in general NP-hard. However, your polyhedron has a specific structure, so I'm not sure if there is a special instance of it that is known to be NP-hard.

Comment: A necessary condition for the inequality to hold (that can be checked in polynomial time) is that any eigenvector corresponding to a positive eigenvalue of $Q$ must not belong to the recession cone of $\mathcal{X}$ (this doesn't answer your question)